# SQL update from one Table to another where ID matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 databases Alpha and Beta. Each database has identical table "Comments". The Comments table has 2 fields: ID and Comments. Alpha.Comments has only ID field populated, corresponding Comment field is empty. Beta.Comments has both ID and the corresponding comments. Is there SQL Query that can update all of Alpha.Comments field with appropriate entries from Beta, where ID matches?

[image: Copy table data]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join results from tables with same name from different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915238/join-results-from-tables-with-same-name-from-different-databases)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: SQL Server 2012, using MSSMS

Ran this quiery:

update alpha.comments
    set comments = (select b.comments from beta.comments b where b.id = comments.id);

It errored out:
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Resolved. Apparently Table B had more records than Table A. Had to properly use Where statement to filter out the same set of records to match with Table A.

Comment: Perhaps you would care to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and explain exactly how you resolved the problem, just in case someone else may arrive at this question as a result of encountering the same error and searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
update alpha.comments
    set comments = (select b.comments from beta.comments b where b.id = comments.id);
```

In SQL Server, you can can express this as:

```
update a
    set comments = b.comments
    from alpha.comments a join
         beta.comments b
         on a.id = b.id;
```

This handles duplicates in an unfortunate way.  It arbitrarily chooses one for the assignment, so no error is generated.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. There are two tables which are both named `Comments`. There is no `beta` table.

Comment: @Abra . . . I tweaked the answer.  That the second table is called `beta.comments` and not `beta` is a small detail on the answer.

Comment: It errored out:
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @matrixman001 . . .  If you have repeated ids in the second table, then your problem is not well defined.  You should explain how you want to handle that.  Nothing in your question suggests that you have repeated ids in either table.

Answer (score 0):

There are already post similar to this request - please take a look at:

[Copy data from one column to other column (which is in a different table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361768/copy-data-from-one-column-to-other-column-which-is-in-a-different-table)

[MySQL: Copy table to another table with an extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425773/mysql-copy-table-to-another-table-with-an-extra-column)

[Join results from tables with same name from different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915238/join-results-from-tables-with-same-name-from-different-databases)

am sure there are others, so you can find one which is related to the DB that you are using.

Comment: Why don't you vote to close the question as a duplicate?

Comment: Will do - missed that option

Answer (score 0):

You can update like this

```
UPDATE Alpha SET Comments=(
SELECT Comments
FROM Beta
WHERE Beta.ID = Alpha.ID
);
```